# Is there efficient way to copy data table?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm using temp_data_table for copy real_data_table

I'm using this maria db
This is my query....

```
INSERT INTO raffledata
            (
                    raffleNo,                         storeNo,                 storeId,             favoriteArea,                 modelId,
                    size,                            personName,             personId,             createDate_join1,             createDate_join2,
                    createDate_web_join,            email,                     birthDate,             isOut,                        address,
                    creator,                         createDate,                isDelete,
                    randomNo,                         rank2,                    fileNo
            )
            SELECT raffleNo,                         storeNo,                 storeId,             favoriteArea,                 modelId,
                    size,                            personName,             personId,             createDate_join1,             createDate_join2,
                    createDate_web_join,            email,                     birthDate,             isOut,                        address,
                    creator,                         createDate,                isDelete,
                    randomNo,                         rank2,                    fileNo
            FROM temp_raffledata
            WHERE raffleNo = #{raffleNo}
```

but if there are too many data in temp_table(ex .. 100,000,00 ..... over)

it's spend much time to copy data from temp_table to real_table.

Is it possible to upgrade this query?

Sorry.. I'm not used to writing English. If you can handle this problem, help me

Comment: If the index by `raffleNo` exists then I cannot find the base for any improvement. Maybe except source table partitioning by `raffleNo`, but I doubt that this is useful.

Comment: 10M records is fairly large, so the copy could take a while. How long does it take?

Comment: About 8 minutes

Comment: Can you please post the exekution plan. It can be created with the command explain https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/

Comment: No matter how you do it, copying 10M rows will take time.  Why does it matter?  How often do you do the copy?  Give us more details.  Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: Because I'm considering Java memory protection
Maybe many clients request 100,000,000 data at the same time, 
it will occur java heap memory error. 
So I apply Mybatis Batch Service when insert temp_data. 
but I don't know what to do copy data.
maybe I was wrong. 
The process of copying is not about Java memory ,
it's about maria db server

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if I got your problem. But in case you just want to copy the data from one table to another you can just use:

```
create table real_data_table as select * from tmp_table;
```

If you want to insert data into real_data_table you can use:

```
insert into real_data_table select * from tmp_table;
```

You could check out the [MariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-select/) for further informations.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Searching for the data to be copied may slow down the copying process. Therefore, make sure that indexes are used to find the data to be copied.